# Sunburst D3 with 10.000 items

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have implemented one Sunburst D3 with 10.000 itens. The sunburst seems to not handle with this amount of data. There is some workaround to this problem?

Using: d3, nvd3, [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/sunburstChart)

[image]

Comment: ^^^^ This. Probably need to split the data up and call different parts when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 10,000 nodes you're thrashing the transitions moving a lot of svg elements, most of which are too small to usefully see or interact with anyways. You can speed it up by filtering the nodes that the partition layout returns to discount nodes that are smaller than a certain angle (d.dx), look at the bl.ocks here -->

https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

and specifically these lines -->

```
var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });
```

Of course if you want to show them all, you could relayout in full once any transition has finished by removing the filter